# How do i delete or edit an Facebook Event?

Tags: asp.net, facebook-graph-api

i've googling all day , and is this event supported ? anyways, here is my code :

```
 public bool updateEvents(String eventID, EventList toUpdate){
            bool success = false;
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(eventID) != false && toUpdate != null)
            {
                Dictionary<String, String> eventInit = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                DateTime start = DateTime.Parse(toUpdate.StartTime);
                String startTime = start.ToString("s");
                start = DateTime.Parse(toUpdate.EndTime);
                String endTime = start.ToString("s");
                eventInit.Add("name", toUpdate.EventName);
                eventInit.Add("description", toUpdate.Description);
                eventInit.Add("start_time", startTime);
                eventInit.Add("end_time", endTime);
                eventInit.Add("location", toUpdate.Location);
                JSONObject js = api.Post(" https://graph.facebook.com/" + eventID, eventInit);
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(js.Dictionary["ID"].String) == false)
                {
                    success = true;
                }
            }
            return success;
        }

 public bool deleteEvents(String eventID)
        {
            bool success = false;
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(eventID) == false)
            {
                JSONObject js = api.Delete("/"+eventID);
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(js.Dictionary["ID"].String))
                {
                    success = true;
                }
            }
            return success;
        }
```

And the tricky part is that , it doesn't update, and if delete, it returns me a 404.

Here is a few things i've tried : /me/events/eventID , http://graph.facebook.com/eventID , /events/eventID ; /eventID ; Anyways, none of them works ... so , is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a leading space in your code:

`api.Post(" https:` for the update as well as a `https://` try just `var js = api.Post(eventId, eventInit);`

For the delete you have the wrong check

```
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(js.Dictionary["ID"].String))
            {
                success = true;
            }
```

For the HTTP delete command you get back true/false from the api, not the id of what you deleted.

Comment: The moment the program hits the Delete function, it will return a 404 for i've tried ... and the post just doesn't work at all ...